# Why is Netty's Http2FrameCodec marked as UnstableAPI?

Tags: netty

Netty's [Http2FrameCodec](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/Http2FrameCodec.html) is marked as UnstableAPI and its javadoc says it will eventually replace/reduce [Http2ConnectionHandler](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/Http2ConnectionHandler.html). Are there any details on why Http2FrameCodec is marked Unstable? In particular I am looking to write a HTTP2 server using Netty with all the benefits of HTTP/2 like multiplexing on a persistent connection, header field compression and push_promise? I don't need HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 upgrade.

Should I be using Http2ConnectionHandler or wait for Http2FrameCodec?

Comment: The javadoc says _"This API is very immature. The Http2Connection-based API is currently preferred over this API. This API is targeted to eventually replace or reduce the need for the Http2ConnectionHandler API."_ - So the developers consider it a work-in-progress and subject to change and they recommend you use the Http2Connection-based API. So yes, you should use wait to use the `Http2FrameCodec`

Comment: Yeah I figured that I should wait but I am hoping to get details from Netty developers on the remaining and completed work, and maybe even timelines on when the `Http2FrameCodec` is expected to be ready for use.